# Sequence classification using oneClass SVM

Tags: python, neural-network, svm, anomaly-detection, rnn

In the code below, I'm using a sequence to sequence approach as a prediction model for anomaly detection. The data set I'm working with is ADFA-LD. The training phase is done using only normal sequences. After predicting the next sequence, I want to add a classifier, which will detect abnormal sequences (the test data contains normal and abnormal sequences). To do this, I used `oneClass SVM` as a classifier.
I don't know why but sometimes the program runs normally and sometimes displays this error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
>
> at line: fraud_pred = oneclass.predict(np.array(x_test))

The code:

```py
  # Train - Test Split
  X=lines[['eng','Class1']]
  y=lines[['fr','Class2']]
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)

  #fonction pour charger le data par lot (batch size)
  #séquence du générateur utilisée pour entraîner le réseau de neurones 
  def generate_batch(X = X_train, y = y_train, batch_size = 128):
    ''' Generate a batch of data '''

  encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))           
  en_x=  Embedding(num_encoder_tokens, embedding_size,mask_zero = True) 
  (encoder_inputs) #convertit chaque mot en un vecteur de taille fix
  encoder = GRU(256, return_state=True)
  encoder_outputs, state_h = encoder(en_x) 
  decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
  dex=  Embedding(num_decoder_tokens, embedding_size,mask_zero = 
            True)#convertit chaque mot en un vecteur de taille fix
  final_dex= dex(decoder_inputs)
  decoder_gru = GRU(256, return_sequences=True)
  decoder_gru2 = GRU(256, return_sequences=True,return_state=True)
  decoder_outputs= decoder_gru(final_dex,initial_state=encoder_states)
  decoder_dense = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')
  decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
  model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
  start = time.time()
  model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics= 
        ['acc'])

  train_samples = len(X_train)
  val_samples = len(X_test) 

  batch_size = 128
  epochs = 1
  mod_train=model.fit_generator(generator = generate_batch(X_train, y_train, 
                batch_size = batch_size),
                  steps_per_epoch = train_samples//batch_size,
                  epochs=epochs,
                  validation_data = generate_batch(X_test, y_test, batch_size 
                 = batch_size),
                  validation_steps = val_samples//batch_size)
    df_history = pd.DataFrame (mod_train.history)
    print(df_history)
   #####################################
  #modeles de prédiction
  # define inference encoder
  encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs,encoder_states)
  # define inference decoder
  decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(256,))
  decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h]
  final_dex2= dex(decoder_inputs)
  print(final_dex2)
  decoder_outputs2,state_h2 = decoder_gru2(final_dex2, 
  initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
  decoder_states2 = [state_h2]
  decoder_outputs2 = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs2)
  decoder_model = Model([decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs, 
       [decoder_outputs2] + decoder_states2)



  def decode_sequence(input_seq):
     # Encode the input as state vectors.
     states_value = encoder_model.predict(input_seq)
     print(len(states_value),states_value.shape)
     # Generate empty target sequence of length 1.
     target_seq = np.zeros((1,1))
     # Populate the first word of target sequence with the start word.
     target_seq[0,0] = target_token_index['0000']

     stop_condition = False
     decoded_sentence = ''
     while not stop_condition:
        output_tokens,h= decoder_model.predict([target_seq]+[states_value]) 
        sampled_token_index = np.argmax(output_tokens[0, -1, :])
        sampled_char = reverse_target_char_index[sampled_token_index]
        decoded_sentence +=' '+sampled_char

        # Exit condition: either hit max length
        # or find stop character.
          if (sampled_char =='1111' or len(decoded_sentence.split(' '))> 
              max_len_fr-2):#critere d'arret (la fin de la phrase en français)
              stop_condition = True

        # Update the target sequence (of length 1).
        target_seq = np.zeros((1,1))
        target_seq[0] = sampled_token_index

        # Update states
        states_value = h 
     return decoded_sentence

  y_true=[]
  NN=[]
  test_gen = generate_batch(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 1)
  k=0
  while k<300:
       (input_seq, actual_output), _ = next(test_gen)
       decoded_sentence = decode_sequence(input_seq)
       exp=map(float, str(decoded_sentence).split())
       NN.append(list(exp))
       k+=1

  #seq_preditN = np.transpose(NN)
  seq_preditN = NN
  """------Classification--- """

  seq_preditA=[]
  path1="abnormal.csv"
  abnor_data=load_data(path1)
  abnor_data.insert(1, 'Class1',1)
  abnor_data.insert(3, 'Class2',1)
  X_attck=abnor_data[['eng','Class1']]
  y_attck=abnor_data[['fr','Class2']]
  #X_trainA, X_testA, y_trainA, y_testA = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 
     0.2)

  test_gen = generate_batch(X_attck, y_attck, batch_size = 1)
  k=-1
  k+=1
  while k<300:
       (input_seq, actual_output), _ = next(test_gen)
       decoded_sentence = decode_sequence(input_seq)
       print('Input English sentence:', X_attck[k:k+1].values[0])
  print('Actual Marathi Translation:', y_attck.fr[k:k+1].values[0])
  print('Predicted Marathi Translation:', decoded_sentence)
  exp=map(float, str(decoded_sentence).split())
  seq_preditA.append(list(exp))
  k+=1 
  #seq_preditN = seq_preditN[0:300]
  #seq_preditA = np.transpose(seq_preditA)

   X_test = seq_preditA + seq_preditN
  X_test = np.transpose(X_test)
  #X_test = np.concatenate((seq_preditA, seq_preditN), axis =0)
  print ("X_test")
  print (X_test)
  print("kkkkkkk", len(X_test))

  oneclass = svm.OneClassSVM(kernel='linear', gamma=0.001, nu=0.95)
  y=np.array([np.array(item) for item in seq_preditN])
  oneclass.fit(np.array(y))
  fraud_pred = oneclass.predict(np.array(X_test))
  unique, counts = np.unique(fraud_pred, return_counts=True)
  print (np.asarray((unique, counts)).T)
  fraud_pred = pd.DataFrame(fraud_pred)
  print("fraus.......",fraud_pred)
  y1=y_attck.Class2[0:300]
  y2=y_test.Class2[0:300]
  Y_test=y1.append(y2)
  print(Y_test)
```

If anyone can help me, I'll be so thankful.